# DI Chaining Dependencies with Ninject

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

Consider the following code snip where we implement `ILogger` with all applications using `BaseLogger`. But then we have a scenario where we need to log somewhere specific for a customer, such as a database or to some enterprise App monitor so we have `CustomerSpecificLogger` that also implements `ILogger`

The cTor for `CustomerSpecificLogger` requires a type of ILogger be passed in, in this case we want an instance of `BaseLogger` passed in to perform both logging functions.

I know how to bind `ILogger` with Ninject, but how do you bind two different ILoggers and tell Ninject when to use each?

```
interface ILogger
    {
        void Log(string msg);
    }

    class BaseLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Log(string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }

    class CustomerSpecificLogger : ILogger
    {
        private ILogger BaseLogger { get; set; }

        CustomerSpecificLogger(ILogger baseLogger)
        {
            BaseLogger = baseLogger;
        }

        public void Log(string msg)
        {
            //Log to somewhere specific per customer request
            BaseLogger.Log(msg);
        }
    }
```

I've tried searching around for this but I'm struggling with what this would be called. So alas, I'm coming up empty handed.

**Update**
If I try to bind both, hoping that it uses some type of index to do the binding, it errors out:

```
Bind<ILogger>().To<BaseLogger>();
Bind<ILogger>().To<CustomerSpecificLogger>();
```

Error: More than one matching bindings are available.

**Update 2**
This is called ContextualBinding in Ninject and is documented [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

I think I have this figured out now.

Comment: This may help. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Answer (score 0):

WithConstructorArgument(name, value) sounds like not?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;

public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string msg);
}

public class BaseLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}

public class CustomerSpecificLogger : ILogger
{
    private ILogger BaseLogger { get; set; }

    public CustomerSpecificLogger(ILogger baseLogger)
    {
        BaseLogger = baseLogger;
    }

    public void Log(string msg)
    {
        //Log to somewhere specific per customer request
        BaseLogger.Log(msg);
    }
}

// kernel.Load() in Program.Main() automatically load and bind this.
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
#if true // or some App.config, anything...
        Bind<ILogger>().To<BaseLogger>().InSingletonScope();
#else
        Bind<ILogger>().To<CustomerSpecificLogger>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("baseLogger", new BaseLogger());
#endif
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var logger = kernel.Get<ILogger>();

        logger.Log("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesnt work - still get the runtime multiple bindings error. I see what you are going for, but that pattern seems like it would break if I have more than two instances of ILogger and need to chain them all together.

Comment: Really? I bound only one interface by restricting pragmatic closure. Nothing failed...

Comment: If you wanted named bindings, use

...
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ILogger>().To<BaseLogger>().InSingletonScope().Named("BaseLogger");
        Bind<ILogger>().To<CustomerSpecificLogger>().InSingletonScope().Named("CustomerSpecificLogger").WithConstructorArgument("baseLogger", new BaseLogger());
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var logger = kernel.Get<ILogger>("CustomerSpecificLogger");

        logger.Log("Hello!");
    }
}